# Add a GridView created programmatically in a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

I am trying to insert a GridView I created in Java in a RelativeLayout alredy created in xml.
The error I receive is "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView" and it crashes my application every time it gets to the addView function.
I have try creating a LinearLayout insted of the Relative one and still the same error.

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.work.app2.Main3Activity">

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/buttonDel" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/RL">

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Java:

```
RelativeLayout RelView;
private void addButton() {
    RelView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL);
    GridView GV = new GridView(this);
    GV.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
           ));

    GV.setColumnWidth(100);
    GV.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
    GV.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);

    GV.addView(RelView);//<-----Problem here

    GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(Main3Activity.this,IconsL,Icons2L,nstring);

    RelatLayout.setAdapter(adapter);

    RelatLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View view, int position, long id) {
            showMessage("ss", "click"+position);
        }

    });
    }
```

Comment: do you mean `RelView.addView(GV)`?

Comment: The first thing is that in your xml, the closing tag for your relative layout(id = RL) is missing..After fixing that, you add your grid view to the rl view after setting all your adapters...So, add 'rl.addview(gridview)' as the last line after you have set all the requirements for your grid view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the relative layout to the grid view. Try doing the opposite `RelView.addView(GV)`

Comment: yep, I was missing RelView.addView(GV), now it works, Thanks